# Can you idle in more than one game at the same time?

Tags: steam, steam-trading-cards

I want to get trading cards for lots of games. I know I can idle in a game and earn my drops in it, but can I idle in multiple games at the same time and accrue drops for all of them?

Comment: I had a different question, and one of the answers on my question contains the answer to your question. You have been to my question in the past, and even posted an "answer" that doesn't answer my question, but asks the question shown here. So I am wondering, why would you ask this question?

Comment: @Shiester please tone down the attitude.

Comment: Speaking as someone who's earned over $25 selling trading cards, it is *totally* worth it.

Comment: @ObliviousSage I dunno how worth it is _today_, but it certainly was worth it in private beta :)

Comment: At first I thought you couldn't, because Steam does not allow running multiple games concurrently. I then opened the launchers for *Total War Rome II* and *Tomb Raider*, as well as the games *Terraria* and *Papers Please*. Steam did not prevent me from running all these concurrently. It is possible to earn cards by simply having the launcher opened (without actually being ingame), but since I already got all card drops for all these games (*Papers Please* does not feature cards), I couldn't verify if unlocking the cards itself works, sorry.

Answer (score 4):

The Simple answer is, **Yes**. But Games with Launchers are the Best to Idle in like: *Borderlands* 2 or *Tomb Raider*. Although you can Idle with Multiple Games you still have the droprate across all those games you have open, Which Means you won't be Earning more than having one game open. Also you will need a beefy computer to do this!